# Seeking offline predicted travel time service, package or software?

Tags: software-recommendations, route, predicates

I am looking for a service/package/sw that will return the **predicted travel time** (not real time) between two points and the departure day and time. The predicted travel time **must take into account the traffic** and have a **global coverage**.

I am aware that there are online services like google maps that have such service but I **can not afford the API latency**, as I need to query a lot (and don't know in advanced, what I will call).

I am looking for a solution that will run behind the firewall and respond quickly with estimation based on offline historical data.

This data can be synchronized with the online fresh data on a daily / weekly basis.

**Any solution (free or paid)?**

Comment: For software recommendations I think you should ask at the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange?

Comment: @PolyGeo, this is a very GIS application question, which only GIS experts, who use services/sw can answer.

Comment: If you take the [Tour], you'll see that this group of GIS experts doesn't really want to wade into the topic of highly subjective software recommendations. You're more likely to find folks willing to answer over in [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: The software part of this Q is trivial, the data part isn't. Basically, the workflow described above requires a local copy of worldwide traffic data without the vendor retaining control of the data. If such exists, I think it will be prohibitively expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes offline data and software exists that is capable of this - but as @underdark mentions - licenses will be costly.

Speed data is usually averaged into AM/PM Peak, Off Peak etc. time periods and attached to a road network, on which the GIS software can calculate drive-times.

Some sources:
https://www.pitneybowes.com/us/data/street-data.html
https://www.allmapdata.com/products/digital-map-data/navigation-and-speeds/